# Webparts connection

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, custom-list, connected-web-parts

I have a page with 4 **connected list view**. (let s say view A, B, C, D).
The views are connected so that I can filter the views. (used the SharePoint default connection).

List A is connected to list B. 
List B is connected to list C. 
List C is connected to list D.

My issue is that when I select an item in the A view, the B view change correctly but none item is selected so in the C view I still see the old value.

How can I **select the first item**? (so also the C view wll be filter and so on the D view).

Thanks

Comment: This link is for 2007. Give it a try http://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-moss-2007-version/. Here instead of selecting first row, we are displaying a message so the user can select a row for filtering.